# Specification for tuple fields inside a record

Tags: erlang

See my attempt at a record definition below. The Erlang compiler doesn't consider the `key` field definition as valid syntax.

Is there a way to accomplish something similar, without making key a record or just a undefined tuple structure like `key :: tuple()`?

```
-record(spot, { 
      key :: {id :: integer(), version:: integer(), live :: boolean()},
      name :: binary(), 
      short_description :: binary(), 
      address1 :: binary(), 
      address2 :: binary(),
      address3 :: binary(),
      postalcode :: binary(),
      city :: binary(),
      phone :: binary(),
      website_url :: binary(),
      menu_url :: binary(),
      last_modified_at :: erlang:timestamp()}).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{id :: integer(), version:: integer(), live :: boolean()}` is not valid type specification. You can use record definition or you have to specify only type information which is `{integer(), integer(), boolean()}`.

So using record would look like.

```
-record(spot_key, {
         id :: integer(),
         version:: integer(),
         live :: boolean()
     }).

-record(spot, { 
      key :: #spot_key{},
      name :: binary(), 
      short_description :: binary(), 
      address1 :: binary(), 
      address2 :: binary(),
      address3 :: binary(),
      postalcode :: binary(),
      city :: binary(),
      phone :: binary(),
      website_url :: binary(),
      menu_url :: binary(),
      last_modified_at :: erlang:timestamp()
    }).
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to create record for key, you cannot use field names in the key tuple.
If you remove that field names , I believe compiler will be able to eat it.

I mean try instead of

```
   -record(spot, { 
      key :: {id :: integer(), version:: integer(), live :: boolean()},
      name :: binary(),
```

write

```
   -record(spot, { 
      key :: {integer(), integer(), boolean()},
      name :: binary(),
```